# Writing a SQL query to return data from multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I am working through a database textbook and I am stuck on a certain exercise.

Question 6 on page 74 of the [book](http://www.acs.uwinnipeg.ca/rmcfadyen/CreativeCommons/Relational%20Databases%20and%20Microsoft%20Access%20V3.0.pdf), and a copy of the database I am working on can be found [here](http://www.acs.uwinnipeg.ca/rmcfadyen/CreativeCommons/Company.accdb). On page 72 you can see portions of the two tables. I want to write an SQL query that will return the name of the department, the last name of the manager/head of the department and the last name of the employees who work there.

E.g.

Marketing Herring Holt

So I have been able to print the department name, the empId of the manager and the last names of the employees with the following SQL query.

```
SELECT department, manager, lastName
FROM Department d
INNER JOIN Employee e
ON e.dept = d.deptId;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use self join to get the manager-employee relationship records

```
SELECT d.department, 
       e1.lastname As Employee, 
       e.lastname As Manager
FROM   (employee AS e 
        INNER JOIN department AS d 
                ON d.deptid = e.dept ) 
       INNER JOIN employee AS e1 
               ON e1.supervisor = e.empid
```

EDIT: The exact solution to the question asked

```
SELECT d.department, m.lastName, e.lastName
FROM (employee AS e INNER JOIN department AS d  ON d.deptId = e.dept)
INNER JOIN employee AS m ON d.manager = m.empId;
```

Comment: Thank you I was able to use your answer to get the solution I needed.

Comment: `SELECT d.department, m.lastName, e.lastName
FROM (employee AS e INNER JOIN department AS d ON d.deptId = e.dept) 
INNER JOIN employee AS m ON d.manager = m.empId;`